# Printing problem only in web browsers

Tags: preview, printing

Under Yosemite 10.10.5 on an iMac, I get the following two error messages when printing from Firefox:

First error message:  "*Print Preview Error.  An error occurred while printing*"

Then, after clicking OK, I get the following second error message:  "*Printer Error.   An error occurred while printing*"

And, of course the web page doesn’t print anything.

The Preview app, in general, seems to be working fine.  And printing from other apps (not browsers) is also fine.

What I’ve tried:

- Tried printing under Safari and Chrome.  Both yield one empty page.
- Tried printing other apps.  All works fine.
- Tried removing     com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.Canon_MX922.plist     No impact.
- Repaired permissions - no impact
- Restarted in Safe mode.  Then restarted. No impact
- Opened console and searched for "preview"   Got the following:
  mdworker(456) deny file-read-data /Applications/Preview.app

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: If you're able to, installing the latest version of OS X would be preferable. Since your problem isn't being solved even in safe mode, it's a printer problem. Check ink levels, then try restarting the printer.

Comment: Thanks, angelplayer.  Restarting printer didn't help.  If "it's a printer problem." I can't explain why problem only appears for browser printing.  All other printing is fine.

Comment: Update:  Reset the printing system using apple instructions at https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201539     No impact on problem

Comment: Update:  Tried Firefox in Safe Mode.   No impact on problem.